# Language model in deep learning - hard time to understand the task

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language

I'm having a hard time to understand the task of "language model".
Translate, speech, Spelling, sentiment analysis, those I understand, but what does "language model" means?! is it just the action of embedding?

I'm sorry for my ignorance, and will be happy to get your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can imagine there is a probability distribution over all possible sentences. The goal of language modeling is to accurately model $p(x)$, for any sentence $x$.

In other words, if I randomly draw a sentence from this distribution of all sentences, what is the probability that it'll be sentence $x$?

(I say sentence here, but you can language model anything from trigrams to entire books.)